# Farseer ConvertUnits?

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

In FarseerPhysics engine / XNA, what is `ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits();` ?

Answer (score 6):

Farseer (or rather, Box2D, which it is derived from) is tuned to work best with objects that range from 0.1 to 10 units in weight, and 0.1 and 10 units in size (width or height). If you use objects outside this range, your simulation may not be as stable as it otherwise could be.

Most of the time this works well for "regular" sized objects you might find in a game (cars, books, etc), as measured in meters and kilograms. However this is not mandatory and you can, in fact, choose any scale. (For example: games involving marbles, or aeroplanes, might use a scale other than meters/kilograms).

Most games have various spaces. For example: "Model" space, "Projection" space, "View" space, "World" space, "Screen" space, "Client" space. Some are measured in pixels, others in plain units. And in general games use matrices to convert vertices from one space to another. Most obviously when taking a world measured in units, and displaying it on a screen measured in pixels.

XNA's `SpriteBatch` simplifies this a fair bit, by default, by having the world space be the same as client space. One world unit = one pixel.

Normally you should have your world space defined to be **identical** to the space your physics world exists in. But this would be a problem when using `SpriteBatch`'s default space - as you could then not have a physics object larger than 10 pixels, without going outside range that Farseer is tuned for.

Farseer's<sup>[1]</sup> solution is to have two different world spaces - the *game* space and the *physics* space. And use the `ConvertUnits` class everywhere it needs to convert between these two systems.

I personally find this solution *pretty damn awful*, as it is highly error-prone (as you have to get the conversion correct in multiple places spread throughout your code).

For any modestly serious game development effort, I would recommend using a unified world space, designed around what Farseer requires. And then either use a global transform to `SpriteBatch.Begin`, or something completely other than `SpriteBatch`, to render that world to screen.

However, for simple demos, `ConvertUnits` does the job. And it lets you keep the nice `SpriteBatch` property that one pixel in an unscaled sprite's texture = one pixel on screen.

---

[1]: last time I checked, `ConvertUnits` was part of the Farseer samples, and not part of the physics library itself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dealt with that particular chunk of code, but most games that have a virtual space (the game world) will have a function similar to 'ToDisplayUnits', and it's function is convert the game world's physical units to the display units in XNA.

An example would be meters to pixels, or meters to x,y screen coordinates.

Having this is good, because it allows you do all your math in physics units and keep all abstract, and then translate stuff to the game screen separately.

Answer (score 1):

Farseer uses the MKS (metre, kilogram, second) units of measure.  They provide methods to convert display units of measure to MKS units of measure and vice versa.  ToSimUnits() and ToDisplayUnits().